# I'll be gone in a whistle. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I can look through like superman,
>
> and could even save your life.
>
> I can fly faster than a jet,
>
> but I'm not out of this world
>
> You won't even know I'm there,
>
> so frequently,
>
> I'll be gone in a whistle.

What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be

> Sound?

I can look through like superman, and could even save your life.

> Ultrasound can produce a sonogram - useful in medical applications

I can fly faster than a jet, but I'm not out of this world

> Sound waves move faster through air than many jets, but do not travel where there is no medium (a vacuum)

You won't even know I'm there

> In most cases, you cannot see sound waves

so frequently, I'll be gone in a whistle.

> This one, I'm not sure about. I thought, perhaps, the Doppler effect, but that would make a higher frequency while approaching rather than receding.

Answer (score 4):

Made me think of

> X-Rays

I can look through like superman,
and could even save your life.

> Used to scan your body

I can fly faster than a jet,
but I'm not out of this world

> Both frequency and speed of x-rays are extremely high. Yet they are nothing imaginary or fantastical (like superman)

You won't even know I'm there,

> X-Rays are not visable to the human eye

so frequently,
I'll be gone in a whistle.

> A hint towards waves ;) ?

Comment: I'm thinking this can't be the right answer because they're found in space, aka out of this world

Comment: I think this only means they are nothing fantastical

Comment: Close, but @Moose is right

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> x-rays

I can look through like superman,

> x-rays are used to view inside the human body and other solid objects

and could even save your life.

> x-rays can detect things like internal injuries

I can fly faster than a jet,

> x-rays move at the speed of light

but I'm not out of this world

> very common to find x-rays in use

You won't even know I'm there,

> can't see, smell, taste, feel, or hear x-rays

so frequently,

I'll be gone in a whistle.

> not sure on this one...

Maybe I'm thinking way too literally

Answer (score 2):

I think it's

> sound.

I can look through like superman,

> You can see through with sonar.

and could even save your life.

> Cry for help.

I can fly faster than a jet,

> However, some jets fly faster than sound.

but I'm not out of this world

> Sound is an in-atmosphere thing. There is no sound in space.

You won't even know I'm there,
so frequently,

> White noise in background, even in "silence".

I'll be gone in a whistle.

> Whistle is a sound.

Answer (score -1):

I can look through like superman,

> Silence can look through bodys, rooms.

and could even save your life.

> If you stay silent. In times your life can be saved.

but I'm not out of this world

> Silence is there everywhere.

so frequently,

I'll be gone in a whistle.

> If you blow a whistle, thats the end of it. Silence goes

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.stackexchange. When solving a riddle please explain as many clues as you can and use the spoiler markup.